# Adding An Image Arrow To This CSS Drop Down Menu?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Basically, I want to add a dropdown arrow only for the top menu items that have children. I've tried various tutorials online with different jQuery methods but none seem to work for me (or I'm selecting the wrong class when I try them out).

I've been wrapping my brain around this one for a while. Currently on the live site, I have a drop down arrow on every single menu item.

Does anyone have any ideas for my specific example? I have no idea what I'm doing with jQuery so I'm probably just putting in the wrong class/div when I set it up.

**[My JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUQ3d/)**

**My CSS:**

```
nav > ul {
    text-align: right;
}
nav > ul > li {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background: url('/wp-content/uploads/menu-arrow.png') no-repeat center bottom;
    height: 60px;
}
nav > ul > li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #414141;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
nav > ul > li a:hover {
    color: #3ca648;
}
nav > ul > li > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #3ca648;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
nav > ul > li .sub-menu a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: initial;
}
nav > ul > li .sub-menu a:hover {
    color: #414141;
}
nav li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
nav > ul > li > .sub-menu {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a check on each parent LI for whether or not it has a nested list inside. You can do this by using an each function and then add a class to the parent LI. I updated your fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/XUQ3d/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('#mainNav > li').each(function(){
        var hasNestedItems = $(this).find('li').length;

        if(hasNestedItems > 0){
            $(this).addClass('arrow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not able to answer my own question yet, but I feel pretty dumb after figuring it out. Wordpress automatically has a class called "menu-item-has-children" so all I essentially had to do was add `nav > ul > li.menu-item-has-children` to the stylesheet and set a background image like I previously had done.

Comment: That makes sense if the class names are already present. It sounds like there is already some sort of script running that is adding them there as part of the template. So yeah, you should be able to just target the class name from the stylesheet. You don't even need jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript (making use of JQuery), will add a class "down-arrow" to any menu item which has a submenu. Now, you can use CSS to add the down-arrow image to it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainNav .sub-menu").each(function() {
        $(this).closest("li.menu-item").addClass("has-submenu");
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
.has-submenu > a {
 background: url("arrow.png") no-repeat 0 center;
}
```

EDIT: Changed CSS to add background image to the anchor tag rather than the li itself.